# Download file from rest webservices spring

Tags: java, angular, rest

I'm trying to download any file calling my rest webservices. I'm using spring + jersey for the web services and Angular 2 for the front.
So when I clink on the front, the webservices get my file but **the window to download it is not shown.**

My rest API :

```
    @POST
    @Path("/download")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Download")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response downloadFile(@ApiParam(value = "File", required = true) String filePath) {
        File file = new File("/webapps/pdf/upload/msg/1/gest.PNG");
        Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        try {
            String contentType = Files.probeContentType(file.toPath());
            response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+file.getName());
            response.header("Content-Type", contentType);
            return response.build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My Angular service :

```
    downloadFile(path) {
      const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': '*'});
      const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

      options.responseType = ResponseContentType.Blob;
      return this.http.post(apiUrl + "msg/download", path, options)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

My Angular component :

```
  downloadFile(documentPath) {
    this.msgService.downloadFile(documentPath).subscribe(response => {
      var contentType = response.headers('Content-Type');
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response._body], {type: contentType}));
      window.open(url);    
      });
  }
```

Html :

```
<figure class="ui-g-12 " *ngFor="let document of msg.documents_path" (click)="downloadFile(document)">
      <img  [src]="selectImageByExtension(document.split('.').pop().toLowerCase())"  />
      <figcaption>{{document.split('/').pop().toLowerCase()}}</figcaption>
</figure>
```

When I click on my `figure` I can see that the file is well gotten:
[image]

But nothing pops up.
What did I miss ?

Comment: Did you check the logs to see if the WS got the call and did not encounter IOException?

Comment: Yes it works, otherwise I couldn't get it from debug view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only solution working for me was to use GET request instead of POST passing the filepath as a pathparam.

Rest API :

```
    @GET
    @Path("/download/{filePath}")

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response getdownloadFile(@PathParam("filePath") String filePath) {
        String path = null;

            byte [] barr = Base64.getDecoder().decode(filePath);
            path = new String(barr);
        File file = new File(path);
        try {
            String contentType = Files.probeContentType(file.toPath());

            Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
            response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+file.getName());
            response.header("Content-Type", contentType);
            response.header("Content-Length", file.length());
            return response.build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
```

Angular service :

```
    downloadFile(path) {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '*'});
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    options.responseType = ResponseContentType.Blob;
    return this.http.get(apiUrl + "msg/download/"+btoa(path), options)
      .map(res => res)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Angular component :

```
  downloadFile(documentPath) {
    this.msgService.downloadFile(documentPath).subscribe(response => {
        let params = documentPath.split('/' );
        var blob = new Blob([response._body]);
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, params[params.length-1]);
      });
  }
```